# Are iptables kernel modules hidden from lsmod?

Tags: linux, security, firewall, iptables

When I do `lsmod` I don't see any kernel modules related to iptables despite I have iptables running.

Is it because iptables have been statically linked into the kernel, and I therefore don't need these lines any longer in my firewall scripts?

```
/sbin/insmod ip_tables
/sbin/insmod ip_conntrack
/sbin/insmod ip_conntrack_ftp
/sbin/insmod iptable_nat
/sbin/insmod ip_nat_ftp
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the iptables module is compiled statically into the kernel. Take a look at `/path/to/the/kernel/source/.config`, you will see something like this:

```
# grep -i iptables /usr/src/linux/.config
CONFIG_IP_NF_IPTABLES=y
```

instead of:

```
CONFIG_IP_NF_IPTABLES=m
```

for the loadable module.

Comment: Here is further information in case you didn't find that file / haven't compiled the kernel yourself: https://superuser.com/questions/577307/how-to-get-a-list-of-active-drivers-that-are-statically-built-into-the-linux-ker